# vue.jsでtemplateで要素の有無を知りたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

現在、rails環境でvue.jsでfrontendを作成しています。
実は、添付ファイルのようにcomponentを作成して、cars要素の有無で使用するtemplateを区別しようとしています。
ところが、何度やってもv-elseの方に行ってしまい、v-if="true"のようになりません。
cars要素の有無は、どのようにして判別したらよろしいでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

環境は、次のとおりです。
OS:utunbu16.04
ruby:2.4.2
rails:3.3.3
resque:1.27.4
Vue.js:不明
[image: ソースコード]

Comment: 文字で伝えられる情報は、なるべく文字のまま貼り付けてください。画像にしてしまうと回答の際の引用や、同じ問題で困っている人が検索してもヒットしなくなってしまいます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。おっしゃるとおりです。ただし、この問題は自己解決できました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 解決した場合にはぜひ「自己回答」を行ってください。